# Making Non-Floating Elements Surround Floating Elements

Tags: css, css-float

I currently have a problem concerning the behaviour of floating items, and containers not wrapping around them.

I have a list of items that wrap floating elements. This is a very simplified version:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li><img src="" />Text here</li>
  <li><img src="" />More text</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS looks something like this:

```
ul.items li
{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

ul.items li img
{
  float: left;
}
```

Previously I have added a 'clearing' item at the bottom of each list item to expand it to wrap around the image. This is equivalent to [Tony Aslett's CSS version](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html). An example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N8tPA/).

Unfortunately, I have a menu floating on the left of the list, meaning that adding the clearing creates a huge space underneath the first item. This is mentioned on the above page under **A Word Of Warning (this is important)**. The effect can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N8tPA/1/).

I followed an alternative solution I found from [Paul O'Brien](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html), using the overflow property. This works like a charm. Unfortunately, in addition to the menu on the left, each list item had a menu floating in the upper-right. With `overflow: auto`, those items are pushed outside. This can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N8tPA/3/). The markup is similar to this:

```
<ul class="items">
    <li>
        <div class="floaty">*</div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="img"></div>Text here
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="floaty">*</div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="img"></div>More text
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to get the 'floaty' element to stay inside the 'item' element using this method? Alternatively, is there another solution I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what the entire use-case is here, but for the `.floaty` element is it reasonable to use `position` instead of `float`?

Basically add this:

```
ul.items li { position: relative; }
div.floaty { float: none; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xB5sE/)

Comment: Fantastic! This works like a charm. Surprised it didn't occur to me sooner.